# I need to Display an specific product page on a CMS page in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Please help! I need to display an specific product page in a  cms page (not the product list). This is so that I can choose that cms page as my homepage. Bottom line is that I need the product to be my homepage. I've tried everything! Using xml codes only displays the product list and not the actual product page itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the "Default Web URL" in the System configuration.

[image]

You will have to replace the default value `cms` by the product url in this format: `catalog/product/view/id/PRODUCT_ID/category/CATEGORY_ID/`, you can find the product ID in the back-end panel by looking at the url of the edit product page.